# How do I get the json data from a python request?

Tags: python, roblox

I want to get the `"userPresenceType"` value from `presence.roblox.com api`, but I get the error `"TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'"`

I was able to get the data using `print(new_jsondata[67])`, but I don't think it is very practical.

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import json

url = "https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users"
 
data = {
    "userIds": [
        1885004527
    ]
}
 
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
new_jsondata = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)
print(new_jsondata['userPresenceType'])
print("Status Code", response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When wanting to obtain `json` data from a `requests` method, you can use the `response.json()` method to have the returned `json` string converted to a python object for you.

Then you can index into the python object:

```py
import requests

url = "https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users"
 
data = {
    "userIds": [
        1885004527
    ]
}
 
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
#print("Status Code", response.status_code)
json_data = response.json()

print(json_data['userPresences'][0]['userPresenceType'])
```

Output: `2`

(ymmv)